# How to get ram timing information (MHz, ...) at runtime from linux on a BeagleBoardBlack?

Tags: linux, memory, arm, beagleboneblack

Processor: AM335x 1GHz ARM® Cortex-A8, DDR3 RAM
Somehow i might be missing the correct kernel setting or just the knowledge on where to look in /sys/...
I already tried to get decode-dimms running and sensors-detect. So fare without much success. I changed the ram timings. But now I'd like to see the actual setting at runtime. Is is even possible using this setup?

Comment: I think you already checked but to make sure: lshw -C memory http://superuser.com/questions/519822/how-to-check-ram-timings-in-linux

Comment: lshw returns only "Bus error". So fare I did not found a fix to this.

Comment: it was same even before you change timings? You run as root?

Comment: Yes. There might be something wrong with the kernel config, but I couldn't find it out yet. DMI does not work an ARM, that's what I realized so fare. Any hint on how to fix lshw?

Comment: Or is there a way to read the "Memory Clock Control Register" at run time somehow?